# extending product view page in Magento 2

Tags: product, php-5.4, magento2-dev-beta

I'm trying to extending product view page, But Unable to overriding.

**catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="catalog_product_opengraph" />
    <update handle="page_calendar"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info">
            <block class="Learning\Product\Block\Share" name="sharing_tool" template="Learning_Product::share.phtml"></block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**share.phtml**

```
<h1> Hi I'm sharing tool!!!!!</h1>
```

**Share.php**

```
<?php

namespace Learning\Product\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Share extends Template{

    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('Learning_Product::share.phtml');
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
            <block class="Learning\Product\Block\Share" name="sharing_tool" template="Learning_Product::share.phtml"></block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```